# How do I get real-time "timeonsite" parameter when integrating with timeonsitetracker.js API in web pages?

Tags: javascript, web-analytics, time-tracking

I integrated the JS [timeonsite library](https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite) timeonsitetracker.js in web page as given in document,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tos;
(function(d, s, id, file) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.onload = function() {
        var config = {
            trackBy: 'seconds',
            developerMode: true
        };
        if(TimeOnSiteTracker) {
            Tos = new TimeOnSiteTracker(config);
        }
    };
    js.src = file;fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 } (document, 'script', 'TimeOnSiteTracker', '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/saleemkce/timeonsite@1.1.0/timeonsitetracker.min.js'));
</script>
```

After calling the Tos object,

```
Tos.getTimeOnPage();

{
    TOSId: 13650383319214852
    TOSSessionKey: "6606159448467693493359"
    TOSUserId: "anonymous"
    URL: "https://localhost/index.html"
    currentTime: "2020-07-11 16:25:17.908"
    entryTime: "2020-07-11 16:24:36.911"
    timeOnPage: 41
    timeOnPageByDuration: "0d 00h 00m 41s"
    timeOnPageTrackedBy: "second"
    timeOnSite: 0
    timeOnSiteByDuration: "0d 00h 00m 00s"
    title: "real-time demo"
    trackingType: "tos"
}
```

On calling the ***Tos.getTimeOnPage()*** API, I see the "**timeOnSite**" always "0" but timeOnPage updates periodically. But on refreshing the page, I get the updated **timeOnPage, timeOnSite** in DB saved automatically by tracker. Is there a way to get the real-time "**timeonsite**" param on page without refreshing the whole page as given in demo page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In demo page, what they are doing is basically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    setInterval(function() {
    
    $('#timeOnSiteDuration').html(Tos.secondToDuration((Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnSite + (Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnPage));
                    
   }, 1000);

}
```

They set an interval of 1sec in document.ready to update the 'div' that has  an id='timeOnSiteDuration' with the time on site calculation.

I think a solution that you can do is something like that: using setInterval and calculating the time on site with:

```
Tos.secondToDuration((Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnSite + (Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnPage)
```

You can set this calc to a variable or do like the demo page, show it direct in html.

Comment: this is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Luis' answer, I'm able to get real-time time on site parameter from browser console by typing:

```
console.log((Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnSite + (Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnPage);
```

---

> 61 (seconds)

---

```
console.log(Tos.secondToDuration((Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnSite + (Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnPage));
```

---

> 0d 00h 01m 01s (1 minutes, 1 seconds)

---

however, it should be wrapped in ***setInterval()*** of 1 seconds to get the nice time on site data real-time.

After exploring the demo code, I came to know that this is applicable only for non-IOS browsers since IOS doesn't seem to support ***window.unload*** events.

For IOS devices, following code block works great to get real-time time-on-site data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Timer module data binding
setInterval(function() {
    /*for IOS demo only */

    var isIOSDeviceInst = true;  // In case it's an IOS browser; set this value dynamically

    var IOSPeriodicData;
    var dateObj = (new Date());
    var currentDayKey = 'TOS_' + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1) + '_' + dateObj.getDate() + '_' + dateObj.getFullYear();
    var dataItem = localStorage.getItem(currentDayKey);
    if (dataItem) {
        IOSPeriodicData = JSON.parse(dataItem);
    }
    var timeOnSiteIOS;
    /*for IOS demo only */

    
    if (isIOSDeviceInst && IOSPeriodicData) {
        // > v1.2.0
        var timeOnSiteInitIOSDynamic = (Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnSite;
        timeOnSiteIOS = (timeOnSiteInitIOSDynamic < Tos.getTimeOnPage().timeOnPage) ? Tos.getTimeOnPage().timeOnPage : timeOnSiteInitIOSDynamic;
        $('#timeOnSiteRaw').html(timeOnSiteIOS);

        // v1.1.0
        // $('#timeOnSiteRaw').html(IOSPeriodicData[0].timeOnSite);
    } else {
        $('#timeOnSiteRaw').html((Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnSite + (Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnPage);
    }

    if (isIOSDeviceInst && IOSPeriodicData) {
        // > v1.2.0
        $('#timeOnSiteDuration').html(Tos.secondToDuration(timeOnSiteIOS));

        //v1.1.0
        // $('#timeOnSiteDuration').html(Tos.secondToDuration(IOSPeriodicData[0].timeOnSite));
    } else {
        $('#timeOnSiteDuration').html(Tos.secondToDuration((Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnSite + (Tos.getTimeOnPage()).timeOnPage));
    }
}, 1000);
```

});